# How to invoke an abstract method from main method using array objects

Tags: java, arrays, methods, abstract

In the below code , I'm trying to calculate the GPA of the undergraduate given the grade point and credit values. But how Can I invoke the calGPA method in the main method ? CalGPA should be an abstract method so i cannot make it static because I use JDK 7 in my exams. Is there a possible solution. I think my CalGPA logic is wrong too...
I'm getting this Exception when I try to invoke getGradePoints method. why is that?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "Undergraduate.getResult()" is null

```
public abstract class Student{

    private String name;
    private String courseName;
    private String result;
    private int creditValue;
    private String regNo;
    private double gradePoint;
    private String degree;
    String grade;
    
    Student(String name, String regNo,String degree){
        this.name = name;
        this.regNo = regNo;
        this.degree = degree;
    }
    
    Student( String courseName,int creditValue, String result){
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.creditValue = creditValue;
        this.result = result;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setCourseName(String courseName){
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public String getCourseName(){
        return courseName;
    }
    public void setResult(String result){
        this.result = result;
    }
    public String getResult(){
        return this.result;
    }
    public void setCreditValue(int creditValue){
        this.creditValue = creditValue;
    }
    public int getCreditValue(){
        return this.creditValue;
    }
    public void setRegNo(String regNo){
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }
    public String getRegNo(){
        return this.regNo;
    }
    public void setGradePoint(double gradePoint){
        this.gradePoint = gradePoint;
    }
    public double getGradePoint(){
        return this.gradePoint;
    }
    public abstract void calGPA(Student[] st);

    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }


}

public class Undergraduate extends Student{

    Undergraduate(String name,String regNo,String degree){
        super(name,regNo,degree);
    }
    Undergraduate(String courseName,int creditValue, String result){
        super(courseName,creditValue,result);
    }
    
    public void calGPA(Student[] under){
        int totalCredits = 0;
        double sumOf = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<under.length;i++) {
            sumOf += under[i].getGradePoint()*under[i].getCreditValue();
            totalCredits = totalCredits + under[i].getCreditValue();
        }
        double GPA = sumOf/totalCredits;
        System.out.println("GPA : "+GPA);
    }
    
    public static void undergradDetails(Student[] under, Undergraduate u1){
    System.out.println("********Student Information*************");
    System.out.println("Name : "+u1.getName());
        System.out.println("Registration Number : "+u1.getRegNo());
        System.out.println("Degree: "+u1.getDegree());
        System.out.println("Subject\tGrade");
        for(int i =0;i<under.length;i++){
            System.out.println(" "+under[i].getCourseName() + " \t"+under[i].getResult());
        }
    }
    public double getGradePoints(Student[] under){
        if(getResult().equals("A+")){
            setGradePoint(4.25);
        }if(getResult().equals("A")){
            setGradePoint(4.00);
        }if(getResult().equals("A-")){
            setGradePoint(3.75);
        }if(getResult().equals("B+")){
                setGradePoint(3.50);
            }if(getResult().equals("B")){
                setGradePoint(3.25);
            }if(getResult().equals("B-")){
                    setGradePoint(3.00);
                }if(getResult().equals("C+")){
                        setGradePoint(2.75);
                }if(getResult().equals("C")){
                    setGradePoint(2.50);
                }if(getResult().equals("C-")){
                    setGradePoint(2.25);
                }if(getResult().equals("D")){
                    setGradePoint(1.25);
                }if(getResult().equals("F")){
                    setGradePoint(0.00);
                }
        return getGradePoint();
             }
    
    
        }

public class Driver{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Undergraduate u1 = new Undergraduate("Amila Gunathilake","UG/2011/10045","BSc");
        Student[] under = new Undergraduate[6];
        under[0] = new Undergraduate("CS105",1,"A");
        under[1] = new Undergraduate("CS102",3,"B-");
        under[2] = new Undergraduate("ST104",1,"C");
        under[3] = new Undergraduate("CH109",3,"A-");
        under[4] = new Undergraduate("CH106",2,"A+");
        under[5] = new Undergraduate("CS103",2,"A");

        under.calGPA(under);
         System.out.println(u1.getGradePoints(under));
```

Comment: You are calling `getGradePoints` on `u1` which is entirely unrelated to the `under` array passed to `calGPA`. Since no result is ever set on `u1`, it is `null`, causing a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `u1.calGPA(under)` rather than `calGPA(under)` to make your program run basically not having compilation error.

Added:
There are a lot of problems with your code.

1. Your constructor signature is something

   `Undergraduate(String courseName, int creditValue, String result)`

which is fine later you are initializing your constructor

```
new Undergraduate("CS105", 1, "A")
```

Then in `calGPA` function you are multiplying gradePoint to creditvalue and save that.

`under[i].getGradePoint() * under[i].getCreditValue();`

that is always summing up as 0.

Comment: Nope, U1 is a separate constructor. It doesn't work.

Comment: @AllenHay please check my updated answer.